# Export data from Excel to Access using VBA in Microsoft Excel ERROR

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access-2010

I'm currently making a service system application using Excel VBA. I have a userform to get the input and I would like to save the import data into a few Microsoft Access tables.

I am trying to pull the data from the userform and enter it into the access table When I run this code have a Syntax error. Please i need your help.

```vb
Public Sub AddDatabaseEntry()

  Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim stDB As String, stSQL As String, stProvider As String
  Dim Name As String
  Dim Address As String

  Name = TextBox1
  Address = TextBox2

  stDB = "Data Source= " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SERVDB.accdb"
  stProvider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

  'Opening connection to database
  With cn

      .ConnectionString = stDB
      .Provider = stProvider
      .Open

  End With

 'SQL Statement of what I want from the database
  stSQL = "INSERT INTO Client (FullName, Address) " & _
          "Values (" & Name & ", " & Address & ")"

  cn.Execute stSQL

  cn.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set cn = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  AddDatabaseEntry

End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming that `FullName` and `Address` are VARCHAR, you need to add text qualifiers in your insert.  Better would be to [parameterize the command](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3578/working-with-ado/12354/creating-parametrized-commands).

Comment: Please add details of the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Comintern says can be explained this way.
Wrap your string variables in escaped double quotes or single quotes

**Like this**

```
  stSQL = "INSERT INTO Client (FullName, Address) " & _
          "Values (""" & Name & """, """ & Address & """)"
```

**Or this**

```
  stSQL = "INSERT INTO Client (FullName, Address) " & _
          "Values ('" & Name & "', '" & Address & "')"
```

As as side note,

> it's highly advisable to change your "NAME" variable to something
>   else, as that is a reserved word in VB/VBA